# SharePoint Online Search - Managed Property

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property, sharepoint-search, pnp-js-core, search-schema

How can I create a new managed property with an integer data type in the search schema in SharePOint Online?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of "unused Managed Properties" named Int00 - Int49.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/manage-the-search-schema#Schema_Tenant_SiteColl_Alias

Basic steps:

1. Create a new Site Column in one of your Site Collections.
2. Add this column to a list or library and add at least one item to the list with data in the new column.
3. Wait for, or force, a search crawl.
4. In the SharePoint search admin site find Manage Search Schema.
5. In the Schema page click Managed Properties, if not selected.
6. Search for “Int” and select a property that does not currently have an assigned Crawled Property.
7. Edit the property and add an Alias.  "MyInt"... what your user will type in a search.
8. Just below Alias, click Add a Mapping and select the Crawled Property for your new Site Column. (If your column is named "Item Count" then the Crawled Property would have a name something like "ows_Item_x0020_Count". (guessing from memory!)
9. Request a recrawl of the library that contains these documents. (Library Settings, Advanced)
10. Wait... and test.    MyInt>5   etc.